# Are triggers available on Atlas free tier (M0) clusters?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I wish to create a scheduled trigger on my cluster and have seem mention of free tier databases having access to them in a few articles. However when I go to triggers in my dashboard it's an empty page:

[image]

So is there some way to configure it which I am unaware of or if it is not available please tell me the minimum payed tier which is required to use the feature.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: It was the chromes cache causing the issue apparently